# $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ and $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$ is $f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $(M,d),$ let $f:M\to \mathbb R$ be a function such that for all convergent sequences $x_n\to x$ in $M$, we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $\mathbb R.$ Is $f$ continuous?

How can I prove or disprove ?

This is a doubt which I had! I am sorry but my doubt didn't necessarily have any other attributes associated with the sequence.

Comment: What is the hint from the question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The hint and my question are unrelated. I should have refrained from mentioning it.

Comment: You should look up the quantifiers for your statement.  "For every" and "there exists" ... things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is not continuous at $x.$

Then there is a $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0,$ there is a $y_\delta$ such that $d(x,y_\delta)<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y_\delta)|\geq \epsilon.$

Now, consider $x_n=y_{1/n}.$ Show that $x_n\to x$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x).$

Comment: How can you answer such an unclear question? You're only making up one interpretation it can have.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the question was clear. @ArnaudMortier I didn't see any other rational reading.

Comment: Well, first, it could be "there is a sequence $x_n$ such that".

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks!

Comment: There is always a sequence such that..., specifically, $x_n=x$ for all $n.$ @ArnaudMortier So it is unreasonable for me to assume that reading, or the OP would be asking me to prove that every function is continuous.

Comment: Obviously. That is not the point. The point is to promote well-written and meaningful maths. You don't answer a question that doesn't make sense, at best if you have time you help the OP write it better.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier How should I have framed the question ? Please! guide me through !

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am not able to understand How to proceed from this $x_{n} = y_{1/n} $ to show that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$. How is $y_{1/n}$ defined ?

Comment: We defined $y_{\delta}$ previously. Then $y_{1/n}$ is $y_{\delta}$ when $\delta=1/n.$ @shakunimama

Comment: @shakunimama he defined $y_\delta$ for any $\delta>0$....

Comment: This is known as Heine theorem. One should mention that its proof requires the use of the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Let me elaborate where do we need the Axiom of Choice. There exists
$\varepsilon>0$ such that for each $\delta>0$ the set $A_{\delta}=\{y\mid d(x,y)<\delta\mbox{ and }|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\varepsilon\}$
is non-empty.

Consider the family of non-empty sets $\{A_{\frac{1}{n}}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
By the Axiom of Choice, there exists a function (known as a choice function)
$\theta:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\cup_{n}A_{\frac{1}{n}}$ such that $\theta(n)\in A_{\frac{1}{n}}$.
Such $\theta(n)$ is denoted by $x_{n}$ in Thomas' solution.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Only countable choice, a minor offence, if it is one at all.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Yes. I know that there are axioms which are strictly weaker than AC and that Heine theorem does not need the full power of AC. However, except for set-theoretic specialists, people usually do not consider axioms that are strictly weaker than AC.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan there *is* a huge gap between C-AC and full AC. And C-AC is what is most needed in elementary analysis, and many constructive schools of maths accept a version of it. I have no problem with full AC, I consider it like Cantor a "Gedankengesetz".